# How to recycle background view of UICollectionViewCell or UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicollectionviewcell

I am creating a new background view each time a new cell is requested as follows:

```
 -(UICollectionViewCell*)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MyCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    ...
    cell.backgroundView = [[MyCellBackgroundView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    return cell;
}
```

Should I worry about so may instances being alloc'ed and dealloc'ed?

Answer (score 1):

```
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MyCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

This line of code handles the alloc / init of each cell and their subviews for you. Memory management it taken care of at this point.

If you're still curios - while running the app, open the debug navigator and it will show you CPU and memory usage.

Comment: The `backgroundView` property is nil on *every* call so it is *not* being recycled. I can see that alloc and dealloc are called frequently -- just seems like a lot of memory thrashing.

Comment: Why not create a custom cell instead?

Comment: Custom cell doesn't change the problem -- in fact, that is in reality what I am doing in my code -- I am changing the background on my custom cell.